# Debugging an ASP.NET page with QueryString values

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am trying to debug an asp.net web form that requires a value from the querystring.  I just want to debug that page without having to go through the entire process to create the querystring value and sending the request.

Any suggestions on how to attach a querystring value in VS2008 when I start the debugging process.

NOTE:  I do not want to hard code the value in the pages code behind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Studio has an option to select which page to start when debugging.

It's under Properties -> Web -> Start Url

There you can enter the exact url you want.

Answer (score 1):

Woot, this helped me greatly!

Simply right-click on your web project from the solution explorer, click properties (or alt-enter), click the Web left-side-tab, and set a specific start page (including your qs param)!